# iCloud photo sharing - member cannot view photos?

Tags: icloud, photos, sharing, album

My friend has accepted my request for the shared photo album but cannot see any of the items in the folder- it is blank. 
On my phone it has 400 pics in there. 
It says she is a member of the group. I have checked the setting for photo sharing is on. 
Anyone got any ideas why this is the case? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you go on the web, on a Mac preferably and see the photos ?

Comment: I don’t have a Mac but if it helps I have shared the folder with 2 other people and they can see everything in it?

Comment: Remove them, re-add them (basic turn off and on). Also, try with a new smaller album to isolate their internet connection.